# Applying RegexValidator (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators) attribute to a decimal type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

**Motive** : I have a decimal property in a class which I wish to validate so that it adheres to regex "^\d{1,7}.\d{2,7}$"

So i have applied the Regex validator attribute to the property

```
   [RegexValidator(@"^\d{1,7}\.\d{2,7}$"...)]
   public Decimal MyDecimalProperty { get; set; }
```

Then, via propertyproxyvalidator on my asp.net page i have tied a textbox validation to this property type.

```
<cc1:PropertyProxyValidator ID="MyValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MyTextBox"
PropertyName="MyDecimalProperty" SourceTypeName="Myclass, Mydll"></cc1:PropertyProxyValidator>
```

At runtime i get this error when validation gets performed:

> "Value to validate is not of the
>   expected type: expected System.String
>   but got System.Decimal instead."

Any idea how to get around this issue, or an alternate to achieve my motive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are built to work on strings, not numeric types. Perhaps you need something like this instead:

```
public Decimal MyDecimalProperty { get; set; }

[RegexValidator(@"^\d{1,7}\.\d{2,7}$")]
public string MyDecimalPropertyString
{
    get
    {
        return this.MyDecimalProperty.ToString();
    }
}
```

Also, update the `PropertyName` attribute of the `PropertyProxyValidator`.

Comment: Yes, this is my last resort. I was thinking if there was some way to provide some typeconverter :(

Comment: Thanks though for this sugestion